# Number of ways to choose five lottery numbers so no two are adjacent

Tags: probability, combinatorics, python, lotteries

Someone stated that in a lottery draw, you have an equal chance of being 1 off of every correct number as you do of actually winning, but this is not true if you have adjacent numbers (such as 7/8). I wrote a program which iterates over all possible numbers and counts the number of outcomes where two numbers are adjacent given a top number. It would be too time-consuming to check all 50 numbers for each 5 possible selections, so I instead used lower numbers and tried to find an equation which I can use.

I've got a dataset of x and y values (where x = top number and y = number of outcomes with atleast one adjacent pair). I believe this dataset turns into a quintic function (x^5) when plotted, but I'm not sure. I have two main questions:

- How could I find the equation of the graph? I have tried to find the difference of differences (similar to quadratic, ie 1, 4, 9, 16 = 3, 5, 7 = 2) and it turned out that the difference after 5 differences was a constant 120. I have also tried to find the ratio of one number to the next. This leads to my next question...
- This ratio turned out to be strangely nice. When x=8, y=0. x=9,y=120. x=10,y=720. x=11,y=2520. If you divide one number by the previous, you get *6 (6/1), *3.5 (7/2) and so on, (8/3, 9/4). The fraction's denominator and numerator increase by 1 every time. Where does this come from?

Code I used (python) - https://pastebin.com/d2bAQVmV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are choosing five numbers between $1$ and $x$, and asking the number of ways where no two of the chosen numbers are either equal or adjacent. The answer is
$$
\binom{x-4}{5}\cdot 5!=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)
$$
It is well known that, for positive integers $k$ and $x$, the number of unordered selections of $k$ distinct numbers from $\{1,\dots,x\}$ where no two selected numbers are adjacent is $\binom{x-k+1}{k}$. See the sources belwo for a proof. To get the number of ordered selections, you just multiply by $5!$, the number of ways to arrange five numbers, resulting the formula above. This is a degree five polynomial in $x$, as you noticed.

Questions on MSE on counting non-consecutive subsets:

[Combinatorial restriction on choosing adjacent objects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288617/combinatorial-restriction-on-choosing-adjacent-objects?noredirect=1)
[How many $5$ element sets can be made?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363424/how-many-5-element-sets-can-be-made?noredirect=1)
[Analysis of formula for selecting $k$ elements from $n$ elements arranged in a row so that no two selected elements are consecutive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832155/analysis-of-formula-for-selecting-k-elements-from-n-elements-arranged-in-a-r?noredirect=1)

---

**Edit:** Everything in this section is only correct for lotteries where the order of the chosen numbers matters.

By the way, the statement "you have an equal chance of being 1 off of every correct number as you do of actually winning" is indeed true, if you interpret it a specific way. Suppose ticket has the numbers $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$. The probability of drawing $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ is the same as the probability of drawing $(a+1,b+1,c+1,d+1,e+1,f+1)$.

There is a small caveat here; the "+1" must be interpreted modulo $x$. For example, if there were fifty possible lottery numbers, then you would have to say that $50+1$ wraps around back to one.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not too familiar with probability beyond a basic understanding, could you explain what the bracket with (x-4, 5) represents? The rest seems quite logical though, thanks.

Also, technically it could be interpreted that the statement is correct if you assume that the numbers are all "independent" in a way. For example, if you choose 2,3 16, 21, 42, then being 1 off would mean the numbers are (3, 4, 17, 22, 43). You could interpret this as being correct for 1 number, 2 off on another, and then 1 off for the rest, but you are indeed *technically* correct!

Comment: @AuraZz It is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). Also, you seem to be ignoring order for the lottery tickets. If buy a ticket labeled (1,2,3,4,5), and the numbers drawn are (4,5,1,2,3), then you would win nothing in a typical lottery.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know about the binomial coefficient as it seems quite fundamental. Also, order is not relevant for the Euromillions, which is the lottery I'm basing it on.

Comment: @AuraZz Wow, the powerball in the US also does not care about order (except for the sixth ball), so I was mistaken. In that case, whoever commented that being off by one has the same probability is just plain wrong!

Comment: "Whoever commented" - Haha! Thank you for your answers, really helpful.